# resolving domain name on Django-rest-framework HyperlinkedModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like DRF to use for serialized hyperlinks:

```
http://<mydomain.com>/api/v1/endpoint
```

rather than

```
http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/endpoint
```

Can this be configured within Django or is it related to my http server configuration (gunicorn+nginx)?

Comment: You shouldn't have this problem once you host your app. Django will automatically configure your urls according to the domain it is hosted on.

Comment: I believe I am hosting the app already. I purchased a domain and am routing traffic to my webserver. The guides that I have read on nginx+gunicorn all favor binding gunicorn to 127.0.0.1/localhost and then proxying requests from nginx to there. Binding gunicorn to a domain name causes an error.

Comment: So this has nothing to do with DRF or Django. This is to do with your server settings.

Comment: @ZachWild, what exact settings must be changed on server?

Answer (score 5):

Just set host header for django.

Example for nginx:

```
location /api/ { 
    proxy_set_header Host      $host; 
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using https, also add :

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

and everything works fine :)